# How to add a listener to the default code editor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add a listener to the default code editor in Eclipse. It should be triggered whenever a new code file is opened or closed. Is there anything available like that? I did a google search for hours, but could find a working solution.

I'm especially focusing the default Java code editor. But once I know how to hook into such an editor it shouldn't be a big problem to add additional ones. The main problem I have so far is, that I don't know what I should do with the IEditorDescriptor I could get.

Comment: There is no "default" code editor; any plugin can contribute an editor and you can have any number of plugins installed.

Comment: What about if I have no plugins installed? Then there is an editor available nevertheless. That would be the default editor I guess.

Comment: But you always have some plugins installed. Java editor, C++ editor, text editor, etc., are all provided by plugins. These plugins are just included in default Eclipse installation.

Comment: A yes now I understand, but it is possible to get the default editor for a particular file type for example, but I still don't know how I can hook into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register an IPartListener2 with the PartService, for example:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(aListener)
```

There are other ways to register the IPartListener, for example if you have a reference to an `IWorkbenchPage`.

The part listener is notified when editors are opened or closed, among other things. For `IPartListener2`, you get an `IWorkbenchPartReference` which you can use to check what kind of editor is involved. For example, to detect the standard Java editor, you can check for the ID `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor`.

Comment: Just a small comment, the interface is named IPartListener2, as stated in the 2nd paragraph ( there's no IPartChangeListener2 ).