# How to detect Files being opened at the startup of an Eclipse-Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, text-editor

I'm developing my custom text editors in Eclipse.
For the configuration of my text editors, I have to access the current file which is being opened.

It is no problem, if the file is opened by being selected in project explorer:

```
    ISelection selection = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().getSelection();
```

My question is: How can I access the file, if it is being opened at the startup ? Eclipse remembers the files which were opened before the last termination, but there is no ISelection which would provide me the selected IResource.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IPartListener2 interface to be notified whenever editors are opened. I talked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10377810/639520).