# Detect tab close in Eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application with own editor. Class editor extends from `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor` and it is added in extension in `plugin.xml -> org.eclipse.ui.editors`. How can I detect when the user closes document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For editor close event do something like this:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = ...;

    //adding a listener
IPartListener2 pl = new IPartListener2() {
        // ... Other methods
        public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef)
        {
            //if(partRef.getId().equals(youreditor.id){ /* do something*/ }
        }

};
page.addPartListener(pl);
```

Have a look at these links:

1. [How to add a listener to the default code editor in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340798/how-to-add-a-listener-to-the-default-code-editor-in-eclipse)
2. [FAQ How do I find out what view or editor is selected?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_view_or_editor_is_selected?)

Comment: this is not useable if you need to detect tab close before the tab is actually closed(something like pre-close)