# How to Handle view parts close tab in RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Currently I am working on `RCP application` with `view part`.
In application, user can able to open multiple instances of same `view part`.
I am able to handle view parts close operation with `menu selection`.
But I am unaware of handling the 'X' i.e tab close operation.

I tried with adding `IPartListener` object to the view part object,([I refereed this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756534/detect-tab-close-in-eclipse-editor) ),but in its `partClosed()` method I am facing 2 issues,

1. I am not able to get the current instance of `view part object`.
2. The `partClosed()` method only gets called after closing the tab, so I am not able to show the confirmation for closing the tab.

What approach should I use to resolve above two questions.

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,

Mandar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider to implement the interface `ISaveablePart2` to your `ViewPart`. This interface is responsible  to prompt the user if the part should be closed or not. Furthermore it decides what to do with the unsaved data.

You can promt the user if the view should be closed with a custom dialog in the method `promptToSaveOnClose()`.

```java
@Override
public boolean isDirty() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int promptToSaveOnClose() {
    boolean close = MessageDialog.openConfirm(
            Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), "Close?", "Really?");

    if(close)
        return YES;
    return CANCEL;
}
```

[Eclispe API: ISaveablePart2](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ISaveablePart2.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show a confirmation when closing the editor, why don't you implement `ISaveablePart2` and its method `promptToSaveOnClose();`

Example:

```java
@Override
public int promptToSaveOnClose() {
    boolean canClose = // Show dialog here and return a boolean based on the users input
    if (canClose) {
        return ISaveablePart2.NO;
    } else {
        return ISaveablePart2.CANCEL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```