# How to customize default SaveHandler of an e4 application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

In my e4 application, I am using the default ISaveHandler(which i have not defined explicitly anywhere) as shown in the image.

I just need to update the icon, title & text of this handler, rest works fine for me for single mPart save or multiple mPart save prompt.

I don't want to create my own save handler UI. Even if I could inherit the original one, that will work for me.

[[image: 4]## Heading ##[1]]

Comment: That dialog is an inner class of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer` so you can't get at it. I don't think you have any choice but to write your own ISaveHandler and the dialog. You might be able to use `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceSaveHandler` to do some of the work

Comment: Yes @greg-449 I saw the WBWRenderer class before. Even with PartServiceSaveHandler, I don't get the appropriate methods.

Comment: What I am saying is that you will have to write the complete save dialog. You can use PartServiceSaveHandler to deal with the rest of the ISaveHandler logic, or copy its code since it is an internal class.

Comment: @greg-449 Got It. I have created my own handler. Can you post your comment as an Answer so that that I can mark it properly. Moreover, I will also post my implementation for others. Another thing if you can help me set the CustomSaveHandler globally for all parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dialog is an inner class of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer` so you can't get at it. I don't think you have any choice but to write your own ISaveHandler and the dialog.

You might be able to use org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceSaveHandler to do some of the work.

To use your save handler everywhere set it in the main window context. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45965999/2670892)).